# Ionic revenuecat "Cannot resolve symbol hybridcommon" and more

Tags: android, revenuecat

I have installed cordova and capacitor plugins for ionic by following this guide :

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/purchases

```
$ npm install cordova-plugin-purchases@2.3.0 
$ npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/purchases 
$ ionic cap sync
```

package.json I have those :

```
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/core": "5.43.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/purchases": "^5.44.0",
"cordova-annotated-plugin-android": "^1.0.4",
"cordova-plugin-purchases": "^2.3.0",
```

Then when I run the android studio this missing libraries shows:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'hybridcommon'
Cannot resolve symbol 'common'
Cannot resolve symbol 'interfaces'
Cannot resolve symbol 'PlatformInfo'
Cannot resolve symbol 'CommonKt'
Cannot resolve symbol 'Purchases'
Cannot resolve symbol 'UpdatedPurchaserInfoListener'
Cannot resolve symbol 'PurchaserInfoMapperKt'
```

All those files found in this repo :
https://github.com/RevenueCat/purchases-hybrid-common
but on the Doc (https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/getting-started)
there is no mention to how to add it ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved with:

```
Android Studio -> File -> sync project with Gradle files
```